# Is it possible to smartly control the camera from a smartphone using a wireless module?

Tags: hdr, nikon-d3200, wireless

I have a Nikon d3200. It has got all the basic features a photographer probably needs.

Why I want to use a smartphone to control camera is because,

- Sometimes its flexible.
- An added swivel LCD screen.
- To add HDR and auto bracketing in my camera's feature list.
- May be more, which I haven't encounterd till now.

If I add a wireless module (my camera supports Nikon's wu-1a) in the camera, than is the following procedure possible,

1) From the camera,

```
   + Frame a picture on tripod
```

2) From wirelessly connected smartphone

```
   + Control exposure triangle

   + Select between single shot, HDR, Auto bracketing etc

   + Start capturing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [quick look around](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dslr+controller+nikon) shows that there are several wired solutions for remote control. For Canon cameras, there's something called [DSLR controller](http://dslrcontroller.com/guide-wifi_mr3040.php) that can use a connected [mobile wifi router](http://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-Link-TL-MR3040-Portable-Battery-Wireless/dp/B00842KJOS/).

[Lr timelapse](http://lrtimelapse.com/gear/dslrdashboard/) claims that this works with nikon cameras as well, using [DSLR dashboard](http://dslrdashboard.info/). I certainly think it can't hurt to get an OTG cable for the smartphone and see if they talk to each other; then see if the route through the mobile wifi router is supported.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Nice list. Also, check out the [Photoduino](http://photoduino.com/) and [Trigger Trap](http://triggertrap.com/). The latter sells a dongle for your phone to control the camera.

Comment: Thanks cornelius. My moto e doesn't support usb otg so I need to borrow my frirnd's phone to test it. Anybody tested d3200 with wifi module in stead of OTG for the above solution ? Because if this app does not work with wifi module in d3200 then I don't want to spend on buying wifi module.

Comment: @Cornelius, Yes I have tested Moto G/ SGS4 with OTG and moto e with wifi (wu-1a) with Nikon d3200 camera. Some glitches are there but did the job. Thanks.

Comment: I am happy to hear this worked out for you! :)